# Como pegar dados de um objeto retornado pelo Selenium com php?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

Estou usando Selenium + Chrome WebDriver e php para raspar dados de um site e, para isso, preciso fazer uma condição com a largura de uma coluna de uma tabela desse site. 
Faço isso com o seguinte código:

```
$td3 = $driver ->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody[1]/tr[5]/td[3]')) -> getSize();
```

Só que o Selenium me retorna o tamanho em forma de objeto. Como mostrado em duas formas abaixo.

Com `var_dump` :

> object(Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverDimension)#19 (2) { ["height":"Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverDimension":private]=> int(38) ["width":"Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverDimension":private]=> int(0) }

Com `print_r` :

> Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverDimension Object ( [height:Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverDimension:private] => 38 [width:Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverDimension:private] => 0 )

Eu quero apenas o 0, que é o width do elemento. Como faço pra conseguir isso?

Adendo1: Quando tento utilizar a função `getWidth()`. É gerado este erro (que só tenho acesso pelo arquivo erro.log do php 7):

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebElement::getWidth() in /var/www/html/inpi/crawler.php:92\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/inpi/crawler.php on line 92

Adendo2: Não há css definido na tag para que eu possa usar `getAttribute('width')`. Mesmo assim tentei e não deu certo.

Comment: Já tentei, mas não retorna nada :(

Comment: Adicionei o código que usei de início

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a [“documentação”](https://facebook.github.io/php-webdriver/1.0.2/Facebook/WebDriver/WebDriverDimension.html), o objeto `Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverDimension` possui dois métodos para capturar o valor das propriedades:

- `getHeight()` para retornar a altura
- `getWidth()` parap retorna a largura

Como as propriedades `height` e `width` são privadas *(somente a classe tem acesso)*, então é necessário utilizar os métodos acima para obter esse valor, por exemplo:

```
$td3 = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody[1]/tr[5]/td[3]'))->getSize();

var_dump($td3->getHeight()); //Output: 38
var_dump($td3->getWidth()); //Output: 0
```

Comment: Já tentei, mas não retorna nada

Comment: @JessicaKeilla editei minha resposta. Adicionei o `var_dump`. Caso você esteja tentando imprimir esse inteiro com `echo`, é necessário converte-lo para *string* antes imprimir.

Comment: Ocorreu algum erro ao tentar utilizar os métodos supracitados?

Comment: Ocorreu esse que achei no arquivo error.log do php 7.0 : >>PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Facebook\\WebDriver\\Remote\\RemoteWebElement::getWidth() in /var/www/html/inpi/crawler.php:92\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/inpi/crawler.php on line 92

Comment: Usei todos os tipos de impressão de resultado e nada.

Comment: @JessicaKeilla você está utilizando o objeto errado. Atualizei minha resposta.

Comment: Como não pensei isso antes? kkk. Obrigada @ValdeirPsr